# Not able to scrape Prometheus http metrics except metrics endpoint

Tags: go, prometheus

I am trying to scrape Prometheus http metrics in Go. I can scrape only for "/metrics" not with other two endpoints "/ok" and "/world". I am using below source code.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/go-chi/chi/middleware"
    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus"
    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/promhttp"
    "io"
    "math/rand"

    //"math/rand"

    //"math/rand"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
    //"strings"
    "time"

    //"github.com/go-chi/chi"

    //chiprometheus "github.com/766b/chi-prometheus"
    "github.com/felixge/httpsnoop"
    //"github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus"
)

func Instrument(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    buckets := []float64{.005, .01, .025, .05, .1, .25, .5, 1, 2.5, 5, 10}
    responseTimeHistogram := prometheus.NewHistogramVec(prometheus.HistogramOpts{
        Namespace: "prometheus",
        Name:      "http_server_request_duration_seconds",
        Help:      "Histogram of response time for handler in seconds",
        Buckets:   buckets,
    }, []string{"method", "code"})
    prometheus.MustRegister(responseTimeHistogram)
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        m := httpsnoop.CaptureMetrics(next, w, r)
        duration := float64(m.Duration / time.Millisecond)

        //rctx := chi.RouteContext(r.Context())
        //routePattern := strings.Join(rctx.RoutePatterns, "")
        //routePattern = strings.Replace(routePattern, "/*/", "/", -1)

        responseTimeHistogram.WithLabelValues(
            r.Method, strconv.Itoa(m.Code),
        ).Observe(duration)
    })
}


// NewWrapResponseWriter wraps an http.ResponseWriter, returning a proxy that allows you to
// hook into various parts of the response process.
func NewWrapResponseWriter(w http.ResponseWriter, protoMajor int) WrapResponseWriter {
    _, fl := w.(http.Flusher)

    bw := basicWriter{ResponseWriter: w}

    if protoMajor == 2 {
        _, ps := w.(http.Pusher)
        if fl || ps {
            return &http2FancyWriter{bw}
        }
    } else {
        _, hj := w.(http.Hijacker)
        _, rf := w.(io.ReaderFrom)
        if fl || hj || rf {
            return &httpFancyWriter{bw}
        }
    }

    return &bw
}

// WrapResponseWriter is a proxy around an http.ResponseWriter that allows you to hook
// into various parts of the response process.
type WrapResponseWriter interface {
    http.ResponseWriter
    // Status returns the HTTP status of the request, or 0 if one has not
    // yet been sent.
    Status() int
    // BytesWritten returns the total number of bytes sent to the client.
    BytesWritten() int
    // Tee causes the response body to be written to the given io.Writer in
    // addition to proxying the writes through. Only one io.Writer can be
    // tee'd to at once: setting a second one will overwrite the first.
    // Writes will be sent to the proxy before being written to this
    // io.Writer. It is illegal for the tee'd writer to be modified
    // concurrently with writes.
    Tee(io.Writer)
    // Unwrap returns the original proxied target.
    Unwrap() http.ResponseWriter
}

// basicWriter wraps a http.ResponseWriter that implements the minimal
// http.ResponseWriter interface.
type basicWriter struct {
    http.ResponseWriter
    wroteHeader bool
    code        int
    bytes       int
    tee         io.Writer
}

func (b *basicWriter) WriteHeader(code int) {
    if !b.wroteHeader {
        b.code = code
        b.wroteHeader = true
        b.ResponseWriter.WriteHeader(code)
    }
}

func (b *basicWriter) Write(buf []byte) (int, error) {
    b.maybeWriteHeader()
    n, err := b.ResponseWriter.Write(buf)
    if b.tee != nil {
        _, err2 := b.tee.Write(buf[:n])
        // Prefer errors generated by the proxied writer.
        if err == nil {
            err = err2
        }
    }
    b.bytes += n
    return n, err
}

func (b *basicWriter) maybeWriteHeader() {
    if !b.wroteHeader {
        b.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    }
}

func (b *basicWriter) Status() int {
    return b.code
}

func (b *basicWriter) BytesWritten() int {
    return b.bytes
}

func (b *basicWriter) Tee(w io.Writer) {
    b.tee = w
}

func (b *basicWriter) Unwrap() http.ResponseWriter {
    return b.ResponseWriter
}

// httpFancyWriter is a HTTP writer that additionally satisfies
// http.Flusher, http.Hijacker, and io.ReaderFrom. It exists for the common case
// of wrapping the http.ResponseWriter that package http gives you, in order to
// make the proxied object support the full method set of the proxied object.
type httpFancyWriter struct {
    basicWriter
}

func (f *httpFancyWriter) Flush() {
    f.wroteHeader = true
    fl := f.basicWriter.ResponseWriter.(http.Flusher)
    fl.Flush()
}

func (f *httpFancyWriter) Hijack() (net.Conn, *bufio.ReadWriter, error) {
    hj := f.basicWriter.ResponseWriter.(http.Hijacker)
    return hj.Hijack()
}

func (f *httpFancyWriter) ReadFrom(r io.Reader) (int64, error) {
    if f.basicWriter.tee != nil {
        n, err := io.Copy(&f.basicWriter, r)
        f.basicWriter.bytes += int(n)
        return n, err
    }
    rf := f.basicWriter.ResponseWriter.(io.ReaderFrom)
    f.basicWriter.maybeWriteHeader()
    n, err := rf.ReadFrom(r)
    f.basicWriter.bytes += int(n)
    return n, err
}

var _ http.Flusher = &httpFancyWriter{}
var _ http.Hijacker = &httpFancyWriter{}
var _ io.ReaderFrom = &httpFancyWriter{}

// http2FancyWriter is a HTTP2 writer that additionally satisfies
// http.Flusher, and io.ReaderFrom. It exists for the common case
// of wrapping the http.ResponseWriter that package http gives you, in order to
// make the proxied object support the full method set of the proxied object.
type http2FancyWriter struct {
    basicWriter
}

func (f *http2FancyWriter) Flush() {
    f.wroteHeader = true
    fl := f.basicWriter.ResponseWriter.(http.Flusher)
    fl.Flush()
}

func (f *http2FancyWriter) Push(target string, opts *http.PushOptions) error {
    return f.basicWriter.ResponseWriter.(http.Pusher).Push(target, opts)
}

var _ http.Flusher = &http2FancyWriter{}
var _ http.Pusher = &http2FancyWriter{}

func homeLink(w http.ResponseWriter,r *http.Request){
    fmt.Fprintf(w,"welcome home");
}



func  handler(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    buckets := []float64{.005, .01, .025, .05, .1, .25, .5, 1, 2.5, 5, 10}
    reqs := prometheus.NewCounterVec(
        prometheus.CounterOpts{
            Name:        "http_requests_total",
            Help:        "How many HTTP requests processed, partitioned by status code, method and HTTP path.",
            ConstLabels: prometheus.Labels{"service": "hello"},
        },
        []string{"code", "method", "path"},
    )
    prometheus.MustRegister(reqs)

    latency := prometheus.NewHistogramVec(prometheus.HistogramOpts{
        Name:        "http_server_request_duration_seconds",
        Help:        "How long it took to process the request, partitioned by status code, method and HTTP path.",
        ConstLabels: prometheus.Labels{"service": "hello"},
        Buckets:     buckets,
    },
        []string{"code", "method", "path"},
    )
    prometheus.MustRegister(latency)
    fn := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        start := time.Now()
        ww := middleware.NewWrapResponseWriter(w, r.ProtoMajor)
        next.ServeHTTP(ww, r)
        reqs.WithLabelValues(http.StatusText(ww.Status()), r.Method, r.URL.Path).Inc()
        latency.WithLabelValues(http.StatusText(ww.Status()), r.Method, r.URL.Path).Observe(float64(time.Since(start).Nanoseconds()) / 1000000)
    }
    return http.HandlerFunc(fn)
}
func main() {
     n := http.NewServeMux()
     n.Handle("/metrics",handler(promhttp.Handler()))
     n.HandleFunc(`/ok`, func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        sleep := rand.Intn(4999) + 1
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(sleep) * time.Millisecond)
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)

        w.Write([]byte("200 - Something bad happened!"))
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "slept %d milliseconds\n", sleep)
    })

    http.HandleFunc("/world",homeLink)
    http.ListenAndServe(":3001", n)
}
```

Can anyone suggest me how I can get metrics for endpoints other than "/metrics".
One more question Can I scrape metrics from application that is running on different port and in different file.

Comment: How did you scrape metrics? are you using `curl` or `prometheus` itself?

Comment: What do you mean by "not with other endpoints"?  What happens? What error, or other unexpected behavior do you see?

Comment: You're not using the `handler` middleware for the /ok and /world routes.